# Am I thinking this query wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

**My associations (simplified):**

Project

```
has_many :users
has_many :tasklists
```

Tasklist

```
has_many :tasks
```

Task

```
belongs_to :tasklist
```

User

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: 'assignee_id'
```

**What I want to do**

I want to show a project resource, containing the project's users, each one containing their assigned tasks.

I tried:

```
project = Project.includes(users: :assigned_tasks).find(params[:id])
```

This kind of works except that it returns even the assigned_tasks that DO NOT belong to the parent project. And this is not what I want. I only want assigned tasks that are children of this project.

Maybe the whole approach is not right. Maybe I should think in terms of tasks first for example:

```
project = Project.includes(tasklists: :tasks)
```

But then How would I organise tasks by users?

I hope I'm making sense here. Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways of solving this problem, depending on your priorities. Let's start by looking at your first query:

```
project = Project.includes(users: :assigned_tasks).find(params[:id])
```

This has the advantage that you're only performing a single database query that pulls back all the information - and the disadvantage that you're getting back *all* assigned tasks, not just the ones for this project. But you could always filter the tasks when you display them:

```
project.users.each do |user|
  user.assigned_tasks.select {|t| t.project_id == project.id}.each do |task|
    puts task
  end
end
```

---

Alternatively, you could just retrieve the project and its users at first:

```
project = Project.includes(:users).find(params[:id])
```

And [add a scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to your `Task` with [a `where` clause on the `join`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#equality-conditions) to find just the tasks for that project:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tasklist
  scope :for_project, -> (project) {joins(:tasklist).where(tasklist: {project: project})} 
end
```

Then you can use this scope when displaying tasks:

```
project.users.each do |user|
  user.assigned_tasks.for_project(project).each do |task|
    puts task
  end
end
```

The drawback to this is you're likely to run into the [N+1 queries problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). It's also not a major advance in clarity.

---

Maybe the best approach is to allow direct access to a project's tasks from the `project` object:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :tasklists
  has_many :tasks, through: :tasklists
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tasklist
  has_one :project, through: :tasklist
end
```

Which allows you to access the project's tasks via `project.tasks`. Associations are [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html), so you can use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) just like you would with any array:

```
project.tasks.group_by(&:user).each do |user, tasks]
  puts user.name
  tasks.each do |t|
    puts t
  end
end
```

To keep the number of database queries low, you can load your tasks with your project:

```
project = Project.includes(:users, :tasks).find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this very complete answer. I really like the last approach. I didn't know you could use has_many through this way, which is great. However, I ended up using the second approach since my rails app is a REST API and the structure of the data matters a lot (rails wasn't happy with me doing project.users = project.tasks.group_by(&:user) it threw a type error). But anyway that solved my problem and I've learned new tricks so thank you Alex P :)